# division algebras in Weil's Basic Number Theory

Tags: terminology, local-field

I have a question regarding the terminology in Weil's Basic Number Theory. In Corollary 5 of I-§4 (p. 14) there is a statement regarding division algebras over local fields. It starts like this:

Let $K$ be a commutative $p$-field [nowadays usually called a non-archimedean local field whose residue field is finite and of characteristic $p$], and $K'$ a division algebra over $K$. .....

In the proof, he begins by saying that $K'$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $K$. Why this is true? Did he simply forget to add 'finite dimensional' or am I missing something? Also I don't see the point why he invokes theorem 5 of I-§3 in the last line.

Thanks in advance, AYK.

---

[image]

These are the statements he is referring to:

[image]
[image]

The definition of a $p$-field is given by:

[image]

Comment: I don’t have the book, and I imagine that many people in a position to answer your second question don’t, either. Please give more background. As to your question about finite-dimensionality, it’s probable that he simply omitted that hypothesis.

Comment: He makes a few umbrella assumptions in the prerequisities, and this may be covered in there. In the preceding paragraph he has local compactness as a property of all $p$-fields (commutative or not), and this should lead to f.d. here as well. I quickly leafed through the early pages, and cannot pinpoint the spot for you, but I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Lubin You are right, I have added the relevant passages.